# Chrome extension to click on link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that clicks on an `<a>` element automatically.

test.js:

```
a = document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_AssetSearchPanel_DialogContainers_GridContainers_ctl02_BtnName')

a.click()
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Containers v2",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "test.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://myurl.com"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
  }
}
```

In Chrome I get the error:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

I'm using the minimum security policy, why doesn't this work?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to automate a process on my company's internal website. There is a button on the page that I need to automatically press. Initially I tried calling the function which that button calls:__doPostBack('...) But I get this error: ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Read [An Introduction to Content Security Policy](https://web.dev/csp/) and why [Inline code is considered harmful](https://web.dev/articles/csp#inline_code_is_considered_harmful). There are many examples to guide you.
This code completely goes against [Content Security Policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

```js
a = document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_AssetSearchPanel_DialogContainers_GridContainers_ctl02_BtnName')
a.click()
```

Comment: You are doing exactly what an attacker would do. You are causing automated actions using JavaScript. It’s typically something an attacker would do, such that a user gets completely bamboozled.